# UDP socket don't recv responses on broadcast requests

Tags: ios, c, unix, broadcast, unix-socket

I need to find out ip of some devices in local network in order to do that i send broadcast messages and wait for responses so, common way. All this happens on mobile devices: iOS or Android. This module is written in C.
Pseudocode:

1. Open socket, configure
2. Send broadcast request
3. Receive responses
4. Close socket.

   Problem is - when iOS device sleeps for some time and after that i run search, i see no responses. Broadcast messages are still goes to network (checked with Wireshark). Also, i suppose that searched devices are functional (because they can be found from other smartphones).
   Problem solves when i disconnect from current wi-fi and connect to it again.

Here is socket options:

```
int setup_socket( void ) {
    int sck = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0 );
    if (sck < 0)
        return -1;

    int bcast = 1;
    if ( 0 > setsockopt( sck, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &bcast, sizeof( bcast ) ) ) {
        return -1;
    }

    struct timeval tv = {
        .tv_sec = 0,
        .tv_usec = 100 * 1000,
    };

    if ( 0 > setsockopt( sck, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &tv, sizeof( tv ) ) ) {
        return -1;
    }

    return sck;
}
```

will be grateful for any ideas

Comment: when C library functions return an error indication, they also set `errno`.  The posted code tells the user NOTHING when the operation fails.  Strongly suggest using `perror()` when an error is indicated, That way your error message AND the text error message of why the system thinks the error occurred are output to `stderr`.

Comment: the posted code snippet is (probably) not the root of the problem.  Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: suggest using the `keepalive` option so the socket does not 'close' when the recv timeout has expired

Comment: I simplified code and remove errors handling, just replaced it with -1 (no errors there anyway). It will be pretty hard to post complete example because there are three layers ((

Comment: the 'simplification' makes the code even more difficult to debug as the essential information is not available.